# How to color the background of the paper in latex?

Tags: color, backgrounds

How to color the background  of the paper in latex?

I want my document to have every other page coloring i.e., say I want the papers to be light blue and light pink alternatively, how can I do this?

Note that, I did not start my document yet, my document size will be about 6 or 8 pages. I prefer using document class book or article.

Comment: You can use `\pagecolor` (needs a color package).

Comment: Can you provide details please @UlrikeFischer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tap into the shipout routine and change the colour based on the value of the page number:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\AddToHook{shipout/before}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \pagecolor{blue!5!white}% Odd page colour (light blue)
  \else
    \pagecolor{red!5!white}% Even page colour (light red)
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\kant[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of shipout?

Comment: What if I wanted to use the document class exam? I think the code should be the same also, am I correct?

Comment: What if I need the color to be heavier that this but does not hinder the clearance of the font also?

Comment: @MarkA.Bromuela: The OP wanted to switch between page colours. The shipout process is one that can be tapped into in order to condition on changing the colour.

Comment: @Happy: The code should work with any document class as the process only relies on tapping into the page shipout procedure (which is class independent). You can change the colour to whatever you want. `red!5!white` means 5% red and 95% white. You can mix colours to suit your needs. Try, for example, `red!10!white` for a more red background colour. Also see the [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor) for some more options and palettes.

Comment: I do not know why the code is not giving me alternating colors, it only gave me the blue color, any advice about that?

Comment: Also, I meant to say that I want dark sky-blue as it is giving me a purple color , Also is there a pink and not red color?

Comment: @Happy: One would have to look at your code to understand why it's not working the way you're using it. As for different colours: Consider reading the [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor) where it lists a whole bunch of colours by name. You can then mix them to finetune the colour you're after. If you have a specific colour in mind, find its RGB value and use that explicitly (that is, define it and then use it; something like `\definecolor{skyblue}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}` ... `pagecolor{skyblue}`.

Comment: @Werner Your code works on my Miktex, but does not work on overleaf. I do not know why https://www.overleaf.com/read/ppvnctkdgxsk. By the way, where can I find user guide for `\AddToHook` ?

Comment: @BlackMild: This is typically because of the incorporation of some LaTeX3 code into the LaTeX kernel as of Oct 2020 that has not been updated on OverLeaf's side. Add `\usepackage{xparse}` to the preamble circumvent this. Check the [`lthooks` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/lthooks).

Comment: @Werner Thanks a lot!