# how to put the logo of my institution on each page of my thesis?

Tags: graphics, structure

I am writing my thesis on a Latex environment and especially in a document of type book. Here are the first lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,two side]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}




\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Το Θεώρημα Μοναδικότητας\textlatin{Alexandrov}, Δημήτριος Στεργίου}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{ςςςςςςςς}

\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}



\graphicspath{{images/}}

\title{Διπλωματική Εργασία}
\author{Δημήτρης Στεργίου}
\date{Σεπτέμβριος 2021}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Εισαγωγικές Έννοιες}
```

Nevertheless I would like to put the logo of my University on the left top of each page of the book. I have put the image in a appropriate folder named images but  I do not know what to do next ....

Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7630/add-logo-on-each-page?rq=1

Comment: you can use new (2020) LaTeX command `\AddToHook` as in here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615246/140722

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex/583319?r=SearchResults&s=3|21.7791#583319 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601292/header-image-overlap-header-line